# Reset sqlite db to default values

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, reset, nsfilemanager

I am writing a reset function within my app which will restore my sqlite database to its original state with some pre-populated data.  The code below removes the database from the documents directory and copies over the database from the bundle yet the data still appears from the old database?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"];

 if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){ 

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]      removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil]; 

}

BOOL success; 
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; NSError *error;

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"]; 
 NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"]; 

 success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error]; 

if (!success) {

    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable   database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this in one of my apps. I keep a pre-built database file in my app's bundle. This database has all of the tables and sample data.

When I need to reset the user's database, I shut it down, then overwrite the database with the clean copy from the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Just close your existing sqlite database, and then copy it from the bundle again, over-writing your existing database.  It would be done basically the same way that you did when you copied it over the first time.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying the following after closing my db:

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"];
    
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    }

Comment: BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"];
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MoneyMonthly.sqlite"];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

Comment: And, does it work?  If not, tell us what the error message is and we will try to help.  Also, if you add the code to your **question** and format it as code, it will be **much** more readable and everyone will see it and be able to help out.

Comment: Sorry, i did try and format it. I don't get any errors but it still has some of the data I've entered from the original version of the database.

Comment: Copy and paste the code to your original question by clicking on "edit" below your question.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Try adding a NSLog statement right inside the if statement, right after you delete the original database to see if that is being called.  Is it possible that you have the wrong path for the existing database?

Comment: I can see that the database is removed and a new one created when I look in the /Users/***/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/3EA6A68A-2AE2-445D-BB0E-297F3C5AB75F/Documents/ but it seems to keep the old data?

Comment: Okay, are you sure that it was closed before you deleted it?  iOS caches files sometimes if they haven't been closed.

Comment: Yeah using    sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: Think i've cracked it, I'm writing directly to the db in the bundle somehow.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that isn't possible...  Everything in the bundle is read only, so unless you changed it before you built your project it has to be the same.